# ansible yum list multiple attributes

Tags: ansible

I am trying to print out multiple attributes from `yumoutput`, but this is only printing out the last attribute (`repo`).  How can I use `map` to print out multiple attributes from `yumoutput`?

```
- name: yum updates
  yum:
    list: updates
  register: yumoutput
- debug: 
    msg: "{{yumoutput.results |map(attribute='name') | map(attribute='repo') |list }}"
```

yumoutput contains the following attributes:

```
{
    "arch": "x86_64",
    "name": "libgcc",
    "release": "3.el6",
    "repo": "epel",
    "version": "4.4.7",
    "yumstate": "available"
}
```

Comment: "*this is only printing out the last attribute (`repo`)*" ー what you posted results in an error, not in printing "the last attribute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I use `map` to print out multiple attributes from yumoutput?

You cannot use `map` in this case.

Filters work in sequence, so after you `map(attribute='name')` you have a list (formally a map generator object) with values of the `name` key only and the information about `repo` is not available to subsequent filters.

---

Instead, you can get the result you want with a JMESPath query:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ yumoutput | json_query(my_query) }}"
  vars:
    my_query: "results[].{name: name, repo: repo}"
```

or if you want a nested list of the values only:

```
    my_query: "results[].[name, repo]"
```

Comment: This does display the attributes in json format properly { "name": "libgcc", "repo": "epel" }.  If I wanted to change the output format as: "name: libgcc  repo: epel", how can I change the output format.

Comment: This creates a Python dictionary object with filtered values. `debug` module prints the object as JSON (or otherwise as your callback plugins do). For formatting output you have Jinja2 templates.